# I want to create a 3d model of a box for my AR App which I am building on ARCORE. What do I use?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I am new to animation or models, I am building an AR app which requires me to create 3d animations for example

1) A 3d representation of a box that rotates and shows all details.

2) A 3d representation of lets say a burger or a tree.

I can code what is needed for ARCore where I get lost is where do I create these 3d models? Is there a way to scan real items to create 3d models to be imported in ARCore?

Thanks,
Parag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... i am now using Unity3d to do the animation and rendering. This is not ARCore capability. We can use the sceneForm API for rendering the 3d model.